# How to configure Microsoft SQL server management visual studio

Tags: sql-server, sql, ssms

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to desktop-57.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

### The network path was not found

Answer (score 0):

Type services in the windows search bar. Look for "sql server" service, right click and select start service. Try connecting again.

See this post as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332418/cannot-connect-to-pc-name-sqlexpress/31765026